# Splitting ca cert using OpenSSL -cacerts

Tags: curl, openssl

I'm trying to Convert a .pfx certificate file into three different certificates for the client, the private key and the certification authority certificate.These are to be used in a curl command after converting.

When I run following openssl command on my .pfx file, the ca.pem generated is blank. No error was given. Please let me know the reason for the ca.pem file being empty.

```
openssl pkcs12 -in abcd.pfx -out ca.pem -cacerts -nokeys
```

The client.pem and key.pem were generated as expected though using following commands.

```
openssl pkcs12 -in abcd.pfx -out client.pem -clcerts -nokeys
openssl pkcs12 -in abcd.pfx -out key.pem -nocerts
```